# Extra pixels hiding out somewhere (HTML/CSS)

Tags: html, css, layout, grid

So I have this site I'm working on and everyone is pretty happy with it, but for some reason there are maybe 15-30 extra pixels chilling out on the right hand side. I played with it a bunch to see if I can fix it, but it appears that everything I do to fix extra pixels on the right side creates more extra pixels somewhere else.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="grid-container outline">
        <nav>
            <ul><div class="floatleft">
                <li><a href="#" width="50" height="50"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="img/twitter.png" width="50" height="50"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="img/instagram.png" width="50" height="50"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="img/youtube.png" width="50" height="50"></a></li>
            </div>
            <div class="floatright">
                <li><a href="#trump"><img src="img/ghfjg.png" width="50" height="50"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="img/nufj.png" width="50" height="50"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="img/ykg.png" width="50" height="50"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="img/oiyg.png" width="50" height="50"></a></li>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <header>
        <div class="col-6"
        <div id="logo" align="center">
            <img src="img/logo2.png">
            <h1>#Be Animated</h1>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main><!--start the grid-->
        <!--main top section-->
        <div class="row"> 
            <div id="demo" class="col-6">
                <iframe width="800" height="450" src="#" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6b">
                <h1> Copy is here</h1><br>
                <a href="#"><img src="img/appstore2.png" width="150" height="50"></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
        </div>
        <!---Featured Apps-->
        <div class="featuredApps"><a name="app1">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-1"></div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <h3>Featured Apps</h3>
                    <h2>app1</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-1"></div>
                <div class="col-1">
                    <img src="img/ytfh.png" align="right" width="150" height="150">
                </div>
                <div class="col-2" id="copy">
                    <p>copy here</p>
                </div></a>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-1"></div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <h2>SOMETHING HERE</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-1b"></div>
                <div class="col-2">
                    <p>copy here</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1">
                    <a href="https://LINKAGE"><img src="img/UTFGH.png" align="left" width="150" height="150"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-1"></div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <h2>OUAZ 3D<br>
                        Once Upon a Zombie</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-1"></div>
                    <div class="col-1">
                        <a href="https://MORE LINKAGE"><img src="img/oLKJHL.png" align="right" width="150" height="150"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <p>BLAHBLAHVJGHFJHFHJ</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-1"></div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <h2>IOYJGu</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-1b"></div>
                    <div class="col-2" id="copy">
                        <p>JKFGHDS</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-1">
                        <a href="https://LINK"><img src="img/JHG.png" align="left" width="150" height="150"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <!---more fun with Nito-->
            <div class="LINK">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <h2>ILULUGKGLKJ</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <a href="#IYTFHG"><img src="img/LIH.png" width="100" height="100"></a>
                        <a href="LK7715?mt=8"><img src="img/nito250.png" width="100" height="100"></a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
        <footer>
            <div class="col-6">
                <img src="img/footer_test.png">
                <p>
                    Copyright ©2016D SANA York, NY.
                    <a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**CSS:**

```
  *{
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: lighter;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #3e3e3e;

}

body{
    background: #91b0cd;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#91b0cd, white); /*gradient for safari*/
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#91b0cd, white); /*gradient for opera*/
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#91b0cd, white); /*gradient for firefox*/
    background: linear-gradient(#91b0cd, white); 
    align: center;

}
/*p{
    font-weight: lighter;
    color: #3e3e3e;
}*/

header{
    padding: 30px 0 0 0;
}

h1{
    font-size: 24px;
    color: white;
}

h2{
  font-size: 26px;
}

h3{
    margin-top: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
}

iframe{
    max-width:100%;
}

ul {
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav li{
    display: inline;
}

img{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

footer{
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: center;
    /*padding: 180px 0 0 0;
    /*background-image: url("img/footer_test.png");*/
    max-width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:center bottom;
    background-size: 100%;
}

footer p{
    /*background-image: url("img/footer_test.png");*/
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    /*opacity: 0.75;*/
    font-weight: bold;
}
.floatleft {
    float:left;
}
.floatright {
    float:right;
}

.featuredApps{
    /*margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;*/
    color: #3e3e3e;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.featuredApps p{
    color: #3e3e3e;
}

.nitofam img{
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
#demo img{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#nav{
    align: center;
    repeat: no-repeat;
}

#logo img{
    width: 15%;
    height: 15%;
}



.grid-container{
    width: 100%; 
    max-width: 1800px;      
}

/*-- our cleafix hack -- */ 
.row:before, 
.row:after {
    content:"";
    display: table ;
    clear:both;
}

[class*='col-'] {
    float: left; 
    min-height: 1px; 
    width: 16.66%; 
    /*-- our gutter -- */
    padding: 12px; 
    /*background-color: #FFDCDC;*/
}


.col-1{ width: 16.66%; }
.col-1a{width: 20%;}
.col-1b{width: 25%;}
.col-2{ width: 33.33%; }
.col-3{ width: 50%;    }
.col-4{ width: 66.66%; }
.col-5{ width: 83.33%; }
.col-6{ width: 100%;   }
.col-6b{ width: 70%; margin-left: 15%; margin-right: 15%;}

/*.outline, .outline *{
    outline: 1px solid #F6A1A1; 
}*/

/*-- some extra column content styling --*/
[class*='col-'] > p {
    /*background-color: #FFC2C2; */
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    nav { 
        height: auto;
    }
    nav ul {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        height: auto;
    }
    nav li {
        width: 50%;
        /*float: center;*/
    }
    .floatleft {
    float:none;
    }
    .floatright {
    float:none;}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add padding == 0;

```
.col-6{ width: 100%; padding: 0; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1jkrwar9/

Answer (score 1):

you have a `div` tag that needs to be close here `<div class="col-6"` , close it and it may solve your issue.

plus you have a fixed width in your `iframe` HTML.

give it in your CSS `max-width:100%`

```
iframe {
  max-width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the find - I closed it but it didn't solve the issue :(

Comment: see updated answer, if not fix your issue, provide us a fiddle please

Comment: no fix, thank you for the suggestion though. I have no idea what a fiddle is and am now also concerned about that.... New to posting on SO - usually I just find what I need and am off

Comment: put your code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/) and save it give us the generated link so we can help you better

Comment: Hopefully I did this right - I feel like an embarassment ;-; https://jsfiddle.net/d7whsyr0/#&togetherjs=aArjgpa8rx

Comment: you should add that link in your question, and to be honest I don't see any issue.